# Core Graphics - Is there a way to get/retrieve the currently set CGColor from CGContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-graphics

We can set a CGColor as fill or stroke colour for a given context by doing something like:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color.CGColor);
```

But how can we get or retrieve currently set fill or stroke colour from a given context?

So is there an API something like:

```
CGColorRef CGContextGetFillColorFromContext(CGContextRef c)
```

which takes a CGContext as input parameter and returns it's currently set Fill or stroke CGColour? If not this then is there some other indirect way to achieve this?

I am hoping for the above because the color is set in one class and it is needed back in some other class like so:

In MyView.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set]
    //[@“Hello” drawInRect:rect withFont:titleFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft]; //draws text in the rect with white font colour but removed becasue of API deprecation
    [@“Hello” my_drawInRect:rect withFont:titleFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft]; 
}
```

In NSString+MyCategory.m

```
-(void)my_drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode alignment:(NSTextAlignment)alignment {
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = alignment;
    UIColor* color = nil; //Hoping to get it from UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color}];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> So is there an API something like

No, there is not, because there doesn't need to be.

> But how can we get or retrieve currently set fill or stroke colour from a given context?

The simple answer is that you cannot possibly *not* know what the currently set color is, because you yourself were the one who set it, as in the line you yourself cite:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color.CGColor);
```

If you know you're going to need that color somewhere else, record it in a variable (e.g. an instance variable if the info needs to be available from another method at another time). Plan ahead for your own future needs; that is what programming *is*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Recording it in a variable is one of the obvious solutions I had planned on using in case there is no way to get it directly from CGContext. I have updated my question to give more context to why I was hoping for such an API.

Comment: But as you comfirmed there is no direct way to get it from current CGContext, so I can either:
(i) modify the above method in NSString category to accept one more parameter (for the colour to use) or
(ii) store/record the color in a property of some singleton and access it from there in the category method.
Please correct me if I am wrong
Thanks again for your help. A lot of your answers here on SO have been really helpful in the past.

Comment: The "need" is to avoid managing the state of a single color in two different places. Avoiding unnecessary duplication is basic programming hygiene.